# Channel-Loss and Channel-Insertion-Loss

Tags: usb, analog, communication, transmission-line

Read many time about Channel-Loss and Channel-Insertion-Loss, but confused that, is that same thing or opposite?

Which has +ve or -ve values in dB?

In reference to equalization of USB3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Read many time about Channel-Loss and Channel-Insertion-Loss, but confused that, is that same thing or opposite?

They're usually the same thing. Someone might say "channel insertion loss" if there is a possibility they might also talk about the *return loss* so they need to be specific to avoid ambiguity.

> Which has +ve or -ve values in dB?

Unfortunately, usage is not consistent. Some people will give insertion loss values in positive dB and others will give it in negative dB. Using negative dB is more likely when the writer/speaker is considering the possibility there could be gain rather than loss in the channel (so that gain would be expressed as positive dB and loss as negative dB). But really this usage is so inconsistent that you must consider the context rather than assume one convention or the other.

Comment: I think the answer is wrong. Channel loss is the loss on the channel because of propagation conditions, like free-air losses for wireless and resistive losses for wireline communications. They are usually distributed losses. Insertion loss is the loss in a specific point, and it is caused by the insertion of a device in the communication path (like an attenuator).

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami, you can certainly make your own answer if you like. But the term the OP asked about is "channel insertion loss", not "insertion loss", so I'll respectfully disagree with you. If someone asks me about "channel insertion loss" I would assume they meant the combined insertion loss of all the devices and transmission media that make up whatever channel they're talking about.

Comment: @ThePhoton : You are right. It is in reference of USB so I thought your answer is correct.